# Finding $\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\,\,\frac{a-i\cdot{b}\cos(\pi+\theta)}{c-i\cdot{d}\cos(\pi+\theta)}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to calculate the following definite integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\,\,\frac{a-i\cdot{b}\cos(\pi+\theta)}{c-i\cdot{d}\cos(\pi+\theta)}$$

Anybody has any suggestion?
thanks

So according to the hints, I should proceed in this way:

$$\int_C\,\,\frac{2az+ib(z^2+1)}{iz(2cz+id(z^2+1))}\,\,dz$$

To apply the residue theorem I should know the roots of the denominator:

$$iz(2cz+id(z^2+1))=-d\,z\left(z-i\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)\left(z-i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)$$

Now, if $c>0,d>0,c/d=k>0$

$$|\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}|=|\frac{kd+\sqrt{(kd)^2+d^2}}{d}|=|k+\sqrt{k^2+1}|>1$$

and

$$|\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}|=|\frac{kd-\sqrt{(kd)^2+d^2}}{d}|=|k-\sqrt{k^2+1}|<1$$

Therefore, the only roots inside the unit circle are $z=0$ and $z=i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}$.

$$\int_C\,\,\frac{2az+ib(z^2+1)}{iz(2cz+id(z^2+1))}\,\,dz=-\frac{1}{d}\int_C\,\,\frac{2az+ib(z^2+1)}{z\left(z-i\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)\left(z-i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)}\,\,dz=\\=-\frac{2\pi i}{d}\cdot\frac{ib}{\left(-i\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)\left(-i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)}-\frac{2\pi i}{d}\cdot\frac{2ai\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}+ib((i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d})^2+1)}{i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\left(i\frac{c-\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}-i\frac{c+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{d}\right)}=\\=2\pi\,\,\frac{ac+bd+a\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}(\sqrt{c^2+d^2}+c)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: use $\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$

Hint 2: let $z=e^{i\theta}$, so that $d\theta=\frac{dz}{iz}$, $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(z+1/z)$ and $\sin(\theta)=\frac{1}{2i}(z-1/z)$

Compute the contour integral around the unit circle using the residue theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to follow your hints. Could please check if I did something wrong? There is an unexpected (at least to me) minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a - \ic\,b\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}
               \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}}\,\dd\theta:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a - \ic\,b\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}
>                            \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}}\,\dd\theta}
> =\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a + \ic\,b\cos\pars{\theta}
> \over c + \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a
> +\pars{b/d}\braces{\bracks{\ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta} + c} - c}
> \over c + \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> =2\pi\,{b \over d} + \pars{a - {bc \over d}}
> \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd\theta \over c + \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\pi\,{b \over d} + 2\pars{a - {bc \over d}}
> \color{#04f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}}
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
> \end{align}

We'll evaluate $\ds{\color{#04f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over
c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}}}$ with the
[Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)
$\ds{t \equiv \tan\pars{\theta \over 2}}$:
\begin{align}
&\color{#04f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2\,\dd t\,/\pars{1 + t^{2}} \over
c - \ic\,d\pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{c + \ic\,d}t^{2} + c - \ic\,d}
\\[3mm]&={2 \over c - \ic\,d}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd t \over \pars{\root{\pars{c + \ic\,d}/\pars{c - \ic d}}\ t}^{2} + 1}
={2 \over c - \ic\,d}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\dd t \over \pars{\expo{\ic\phi}\ t}^{2} + 1}\quad\pars{2}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\phi \equiv \arctan\pars{d \over c}}$. When
$\ds{\phi = \pm\,{\pi \over 2} + 2n\pi}$ $\pars{~n \in {\mathbb Z}~}$, which occurs when $\ds{c \to 0}$, the integral in expression $\pars{2}$ diverges. So, we'll assume
$\ds{c \not= 0}$.

> With $\ds{c \not= 0}$, expression $\pars{2}$ is reduced to:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#04f}{\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\theta}}}
> ={2 \over \root{c^{2} + d^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty\expo{\ic\phi}}
> {\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}{a - \ic\,b\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}
                           \over c - \ic\,d\cos\pars{\pi + \theta}}\,\dd\theta
=2\pi\,{b \over d} + 
4\,{a - bc/d \over \root{c^{2} + d^{2}}}\int_{0}^{\infty\expo{\ic\phi}}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}\,,\qquad c \not= 0
\end{align}
The last integral $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{over}\ t~}}$ depends critically on the particular values of $\ds{c}$ and $\ds{d}$.